# How to fetch only number from the string using between value?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a string in which i want to show only 1568.41 using regex how can i do that
this is my string

`*PQS«
        PRICE QUOTE RECORD - SUMMARY BY NAME NUMBER

```
              RETAINED FARE                                 
 NAME    PQ TYPE TKT DES              CREATED       TKT TTL      
 1.1     1                            14MAY USD   1568.41       
 2.1     1                            14MAY USD   1568.41       
 3.1     2  CNN CH25                  14MAY USD   1363.41 `
```

- i used 1.1\s{2,5}\d\s(.+) regex but it fetch complete line.
- i used (?<=USD)\s{2,5}\d{1,4}.\d{2}(?=\s(.+)) but didn't work

There is another string in which same i want to fetch number

```
WPNCB«                                                         
19AUG DEPARTURE DATE-----LAST DAY TO PURCHASE 21MAY/2359       
         BASE FARE      EQUIV AMT      TAXES             TOTAL   
  1-       DKK790       USD139.00     179.40XT       USD318.40ADT
     XT    109.80YQ      19.20YR      29.00ZO         5.40UA      
            2.00UD       14.00YK                                
             790         139.00     179.40            318.40TTL
```

and in the below i just need first number

```
tqt
T     P/S  NAME                   TOTAL            FOP                 SEGMENTS 
9    .3  TMACDORMAN/SAM CORBIN    USD      1177.17 CHECK                  4-5   
10   .1  TLOJ/DANUTA ISABELLA     USD      1341.17 CHECK                  4-5   
10  .2  TMACDORMAN/JACK HENRY    USD      1341.17 CHECK                  4-5
```

in the above string i need only

- 9
- 10
- 10

in this string i want to fetch 318.40 before TTL but when i use regex it also include TTL and when i use between regex in can't work my regex in `\d{1,4}\.\d{2}TTL`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to capture the second question in the request. Note I did change the white space search to a boarder search as this is a little bit cleaner.

This regex here requires the the string be followed by a `TTL`

`(?:\b)([0-9]{0,}[.][0-9]{2})(?=TTL)`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This will find number with zero or more digits followed by a decimal point followed by two digits value at the end each line

`(?:\s)([0-9]{0,}[.][0-9]{2})`

[image]

[image]

Comment: whats your other question?

Comment: your regex is superb it work absolutely fine i have another string in which i have many number like that but i want to fetch number before TTL i will edit my question and past that string to i created a regex but it also fetch TTL and i don't want to show TTL with number can you help me please

Comment: you should open that as a new question